# Chart js show levels on top. (Bar chart with Stacked group)

Tags: javascript, html, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

Here I have implement basic stacked group bar chart

where levels are `'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'`
and here are two stacked group `one, two`

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                stack: 'one',
                label: 'one',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                stack: 'two',
                label: 'two',
                data: [19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                stack: 'one',
                label: 'one',
                data: [ 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                stack: 'two',
                label: 'two',
                data: [ 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            
            scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        stacked: true,
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        stacked: true,
      }
    ]
  }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Output:
[image]

but I want to show the stacked group level at the bottom and data levels on the top of the greed (not every bar)

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an additional x-axis of [`type: 'category'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html) as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
    stacked: true,
    position: 'top'
  },
  {
    type: 'category',
    offset: true,
    labels: ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']
  }
],
```

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        stack: 'one',
        label: 'one',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        stack: 'two',
        label: 'two',
        data: [19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        stack: 'one',
        label: 'one',
        data: [3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        stack: 'two',
        label: 'two',
        data: [2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          position: 'top'
        },
        {
          gridLines: {
                display: false
          },
          type: 'category',
          offset: true,
          labels: ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']         }
      ],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```